# .NET Web Optimization Framework - Combining Bundles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundles

Bundling is great. I have a jQuery bundle, a Angular bundle, a pollyfills bundle, etc. But now I have 10 bundles. How do I combine bundles into a single bundle. Is that possible?

Comment: You can add all your files to one bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in way to combine defined Bundles, so what you would do is just create one Bundle with all the files that you want instead.